# Unable to force ANSI encoding (windows-1252)

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding

I'm trying to save two text files in ANSI encoding for later processing by a legacy system. However when I save it in the correct encoding, it still saves as a UTF-8 file.

I've tried the following:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"));
```

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

I've also tried converting an existing utf-8 file to ansi

```
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)));
```

*None* of the above solutions have worked; they're still UTF-8. The only way I managed to make it save as ANSI was by inserting swedish characters like åäö, which is a hack I cannot use for one of the files.

I'm at a loss. Has anyone got a solution to this issue?

We're on .NET Framework 4.5, C# 7.3

Comment: Why dont you try with `Encoding.ASCII` as 3rd parameter?

Comment: I tried that too, still UTF-8

Comment: How do you know it's still `UTF-8`?

Comment: Nothing in data data that contains the encoding, you are just saving bytes.What are you using to determine you are getting Swedish characters?The viewer/editor you are using is defaulting to an encoding which is making the bytes looks like Swedish characters.When you read the file you have to set the encoding so you view the bytes properly.Most encoding the bytes 0x00 to 0x7F are look the same.Depending on the encoding the bytes 0x80 to 0xFF (one byte) get mapped to a two byte unicode character.The reason for encoding is to use only one bytes for each character rather than two to save memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a thorough investigation and found that it works, just not in the way I expected. As @jdweng said: Nothing in the data contains the encoding, you're just saving bytes. For the most part you're saving regular `ASCII` characters, so when you for instance open Notepad++ to read it, it will default to whatever encoding it prefers, unless you have a special character that hints to the program which encoding to use.

[I encoded a file in four encodings (`default (UTF-8)`, `ANSI`, `ASCII` and `UTF-8-BOM`) and opened up all files in a hex editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/260VA.png) and found that in most cases the `ä` in these files determined which decoder to use in Notepad++.

So if the legacy system uses an `ANSI` decoder, it should be able to open an "`ANSI`" encoded file without special characters. Despite it showing up as `UTF-8` in Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely works. Try the following program:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string filePath = @"E:\tmp\test"; // Put your path here.

            string[] lines = { "ÿ" };

            File.WriteAllLines(filePath + ".1.bin", lines, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
            File.WriteAllLines(filePath + ".2.bin", lines);
        }
    }
}
```

Run the program and then inspect the contents of the files in a binary editor.

You will see the following:

```
test.1.bin contains: FF 0D 0A
test.2.bin contains: 0C BF 0D 0A
```

(Note: If you drag and drop a ".bin" file into Visual Studio, it will open it in binary mode.)